# ModuleNotFoundError with pyenv and python 3.10.6 (not 3.9.13)

Tags: python-3.x, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I've been using pyenv and my own module for years.  Giving 3.10.6 a try and things break.

The following works (new install today - runbook is my own code):

```
pyenv install 3.9.13
pyenv shell 3.9.13
pip install -e ~/code/runbook
runbook -h
```

When I do the same for 3.10.6 the first 3 steps appear to work fine, but the last fails.

```
pyenv install 3.10.6
pyenv shell 3.10.6
pip install -e ~/code/runbook
runbook -h
```

The failure seems to be in the pyenv wrapper script:

```
$ runbook -h 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/runbook", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('runbook', 'console_scripts', 'runbook')())
  File "<path>/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/bin/runbook", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "<path>/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "<path>/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'runbook'
```

I see some similar reports, [like this](https://github.com/mu-editor/mu/issues/2316), but no solution.  FWIW, I'm on a Mac, but an older Mac, not M1/M2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by updating my module's setup.py and adding a `packages` value to the setup call.

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='runbook',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=['src'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'runbook=runbook:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

Without the packages line, any import failed.